# Unable to connect to SQL Server Instance

Tags: sql-server-2008, .net-4.0

I have a simple .net console application that connects to SQL Server and fetches data which runs on development machine, so I guess there is no problem with the application code but when I run this application from server I receive the below error

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)*

I created a .UDL file used the SQL Server native client to connect to the server and it works perfectly. Also I have websites hosted on the same server which works perfectly.

Connection string in my application configration file looks as

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=Server\Instance;Initial Catalog=HrDB_STG01;User ID=username;password=Password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

.Net Code

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "SEL_MULTIJ_FEED";

    using (var sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd))
        {
            sqlAdapter.Fill(ds);
        }
}
```

As the .udl file works, does that confirm there is no problem with firewall? and there is no server issues?

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try an alternative connection string like this?  Are you 100% sure your server name and instance are correct?

```
<add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost\Instance;
database=HrDB_STG01;User ID=username;password=Password"  />
```

Comment: Yes, the connection string is 100% correct and I even copied it from the working website's web.config. I will test with the above connection string and will update

Comment: While using the above connection string I receive the same error message error:26

Comment: Then the next step would be to write out some debug info to a log so you can verify that your SQL connection is getting set up properly.

Comment: can you please explain how to check that? Now I am just writing to a log the connection string fetched from the application configuration file and it is correct.

Comment: Are you connecting to the same database as you were on your development machine?  Does the user have the appropriate permissions in SQL?

Comment: No the database is different to that in the development environment. The user has access to the database and I can confirm this because the .udl file can successfully connect to the Sql Server with that credentials and also the above error says instance specific error.